# Obtaining a formal proof (derivation) in modal logic

Tags: logic, formal-proofs, modal-logic

Assume we have the following statement:

$$\mathsf{K} + \mathsf{A4} + \mathsf{AB} \models \mathsf{A5},$$

where $\mathsf{A4}$ is the transitivity axiom, and $\mathsf{AB}$ is the symmetry axiom. One can show that this relation holds considering required frames or building canonical models. In the former case our reasoning could be as follows: "if there are two arrows from $x$ to $y$ and $z$ then due to symmetry $y\to x$ and from transitivity $y\to z$ qed". We can even write this as a first order formula. I wonder if we can derive $\mathsf{A5}$ from the left hand side logic somehow, for example, convert our reasoning or a first order formula into the derivation. I didn't see the answer anywhere, however I haven't looked for it in every source I have. Can someone help me?

Comment: Been a while.  Can you restate $\sf K,A4, AB, A5$? (I recall $\sf K$ is no premise, $\rm S4$ is reflexive and transitive, $\sf B$ is reflexive and symmetric, $\sf S5$ is reflextive and Euclidean.)

Comment: @GrahamKemp $\mathsf{A4} = \Box p \to\Box\Box p$, $\mathsf{AB} = \Diamond\Box p \to p$, $\mathsf{A5} = \Diamond\Box p \to\Box p$.

Answer (score 2):

1. $\lozenge \varphi \rightarrow \square \lozenge \lozenge \varphi$ (contraposition of AB with $\lozenge \varphi$)
2. $\lozenge \lozenge \varphi \rightarrow \lozenge \varphi$ (contraposition of A4)
3. $\square (\lozenge \lozenge \varphi \rightarrow \lozenge \varphi)$ (necessitation of 3)
4. $\square (\lozenge \lozenge \varphi \rightarrow \lozenge \varphi) \rightarrow (\square \lozenge \lozenge \varphi \rightarrow \square \lozenge \varphi)$ (K)
5. $\square \lozenge \lozenge \varphi \rightarrow \square \lozenge \varphi$ (*modus ponens* 3 and 4)
6. $(\lozenge \varphi \rightarrow \square \lozenge \lozenge \varphi) \wedge (\square \lozenge \lozenge \varphi \rightarrow \square \lozenge \varphi) \rightarrow (\lozenge \varphi \rightarrow \square \lozenge \varphi)$ (propositional reasoning)
7. $\lozenge \varphi \rightarrow \square \lozenge \varphi$ (*modus ponens* 1,5, and 6)

Comment: Cool, thanks, but is there any algorithm of obtaining such proofs?

Comment: I don't really know. Have a look at http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~schmidt/tools/. Although, there are most model checkers.

Comment: wow, thanks, it seems really useful